# How to stop text editor selecting paragraph instead of to the end of the line when I hit shift-end?

Tags: shortcut-keys, text-editor, text

How can I stop my text editor from selecting the paragraph instead of to the end of the line when I hit shift-end?

For my use, the best lightweight text editors are the ones geared towards programmers (they offer customizable syntax highlighting). But there's an odd associated behavior in these text editors.

I've been using Scite for years, but when I hit shift-end it selects the paragraph instead of to the end of the line (the way it does in, for example, the very lightweight Leafpad). This is what I mean:

[image: Difference between Scite and Leafpad behavior.]

Is there a specific name for this behavior? Is there a way to change it in Scite, or in another programming-specific lightweight text editor? Is there a different keyboard shortcut that works in text editors geared towards programmers?

Thanks so much for any help/suggestions.

Comment: `End` is to go to the end of a line. With word wrapping on a continuous line can be visually broken up, but it's still a single line, so this behavior is normal and Leafpad's is not.`Ctrl + Shift + <arrow key>` will highlight one word to the left or right; although it's not what you're after it **may be** all that can be done.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming across the answer as it applies to Scite. Super easy.

Add to your user options file:

wrap.aware.home.end.keys=1

Now when I click shift-end, it selects to the end of the line rather than the end of the paragraph (and of course if you set the above parameter to 0 it does the opposite).